# APNS Push Notifications, Development and Production

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've been working on an app with push notifications for a while. I've been successfully sending notifications via the dev gateway (when I run using my dev profile) and the production one (when running a build that uses an ad hoc profile.

I thought I was all set, since I was able to test the production environment. But when I check out my App ID under 'Identifiers' in the developer portal, the Push Notifications entry is listed as 'Enabled' for development but only 'Configurable' for Distribution.

Did I miss a step? If so, how have my notifications been getting through successfully via the production gateway?

Answer (score 1):

`Configurable` is which denotes that APNS is enabled for that production profile.

Comment: This can't be - otherwise what is 'enabled'?

Answer (score -2):

try to revoke you production cer . because when you use product cer you will get another uuid ..